# What formula would I use in excel to sum a particular category?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I want to sum the values corresponding to E1 only.

Hereby a screenshot:

[image: Values]

I tried using a vlookup and sum formula, but that didn't seem work. Any solutions?

Thanks!

Comment: Please have a read of https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask, then come back and https://superuser.com/posts/1773528/edit your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the reason for which the `SumIf()` worksheet function exists, like in this example:

Formula: `=SUMIF(B2:B10,"E1",A2:A10)`

Screenshot:

[image]